# How to design the dependency for a object being accessed by lots of classes, if not using Singleton?

Tags: design-patterns, singleton

In my client application, there is only one user, the user can login, or logout, or "go offline". The UI and behavior change a lot when the the "member status" of the user is different.

So the "member status" object is needed by lots of classes.

I used Singleton to implement it, so every class can get the "member status" easily, but now the coupling is high and harder to do unit tests properly.
Is there a good design pattern for this(mediator or facade maybe?), or I have to do Dependency Injection to more than 20 classes?

Or I should try a "dependency injection container"? I'm using MFC & C++ .

Comment: When you are talking about dependency injection and singleton, are you implying that there is only one member in your entire system? Or you have a bean for every member in your system? Feel like this is an important detail and could change the answer completely. If either is not true, which member's status are you injecting? Your question needs more detail on the application.

Comment: Hi tinker, there can be only one user logged in or "go offline/invisible" in my client app. I tried to do some dependency injection, and use Service Locator pattern mentioned [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/40637/146950) to make the "member status" object accessed by other classes. It's still ugly though.

Comment: @pac It's still ugly because [Service Locator is an anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern). You may want to consider [proper Dependency Injection](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Succeeding-Dependency-Injection), but it's not going to magically fix your code.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Thanks for your great article, I'll start study it and your book to apply these techniques in my codes.